# Selecting items from a dropdown list with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to select the different elements from a dropdown list using Selenium but I come across the following error message:

> NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 21 driver.get(next_url)
> 22
> ---> 23 sel = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_id23:j_id44"]'))
> 24
> 25 sel.select_by_visible_text("A CORUÑA")

---

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

start_time = time.time()

name_abogado = []
surname_abogado = []
num_col_abogado = []
province_abogado = []

next_url = "https://www.abogacia.es/servicios-abogacia/censo-de-letrados/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get(next_url)

sel = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_id23:j_id44"]'))
    
sel.select_by_visible_text("A CORUÑA")
        
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
button = wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="j_id23:idBuscar"]')))
button.click()
    
time.sleep(1)
    
abogados = driver.find_element_by_class_name(' iceRowSelMouseOver')
        
print(abogados)
```

Comment: is URL `https://www.abogacia.es/servicios-abogacia/censo-de-letrados/` correct ? I don't see any drop down tho.. Probably it's a access denied.. anyway share HTML code, and check if there an iframe involved

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here:

1. You are missing a delay / wait before

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_id23:j_id44"]')
```

You should add a wait there, like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="j_id23:j_id44"]')))
sel = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_id23:j_id44"]'))
```

2. You locator seems to be wrong.
   I can't reach that page, but the `'//*[@id="j_id23:j_id44"]'` is not seems to be a stable XPath expression

Comment: I don't think so it has anything to do with Explicit wait, I guess it's iframe issue.

Comment: He did not have any kind of wait or sleep there, also no use of implicit wait, so it will fail anyway

Comment: waits are good to have but not necessary to have. You can automate `Google search` without any wait, and probably even can select without waits.

Comment: I'm quite sure this is not the situation here

Answer (score 0):

Element you are trying to access is inside a frame. Switch to the frame by

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//iframe[contains(@src,'homeColegiados')]"))


select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//select[@class='iceSelOneMnu']"))
select.select_by_visible_text("A CORUÑA")
```

Comment: Thank you @itronic1990, that resolves the issue. However, I don't really understand the frame mechanics, so can't get to the next step which is accessing the first element of A Coruña lawyers, contained within the xpath: //*[@id="j_id23:tablaElementos:0"]. Many thanks

Comment: I have already upvoted it :). To follow up on this... how would I locate the xpath element //*[@id="j_id23:tablaElementos:0"]. I have used the same method you outlined above to locate the button, but it's apparently not finding the element either...

Comment: what element is @id="j_id23:tablaElementos:0?

Comment: The first lawyers in A Coruña... I want to download all the elements from the table (name, surname, etc).

Comment: You did not upvote the answer btw. To access the table rows, use the xpath: .//table[@class='iceDatTbl tablaElementos']/tbody/tr and store it in a collection. Iterate through the collection and get the values

Comment: I did but apparently i don't have enough reputation to upvote it. The webelement you suggest is not iterable. Thanks

Comment: What you mean by its not iterable? Are you getting any error?